# How to map generic collections with Spring Data(MongoDB)?

Tags: java, collections, mongodb, spring-data

I have some problems with mapping my inner collection.
Items can have different content types. Here is my Item class:

```
@Document(collection = "items")
public class Item{
@Id
private ObjectId id;   
private List<? super Content> content;
...
}
```

Content is a base class for different content for this Item.

```
public class YoutubeVideo implements Content{
     private String url;
}

public class Image implements Content{
     private String location;
}
...
```

After saving (saving finishing with no problems) Item with one Image and two YoutubeVideo classes in content collection i getting this JSON

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4e423dcf7f3a0d12265da46c"} 
"content" : [ 
{ "location" : "hdd path"} , { "url" : "url path"} , { "url" : "url path"}
]}
```

It is not this JSON I expected to see. And understandable why it is not possible to load and deserialize this document.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can not map ? super trngl.mongo.domain.content.Content
```

How you would map this kind of object? I do not want to serialize and deserialize objects manualy. Is it possible?

Found interestion converters class: [mapping-explicit-converters](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/1.0.0.M3/reference/html/#mapping-explicit-converters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be sufficient to use `List<Content>` as you can't access the concrete types from a mixed content list anyway. (Btw. super is definitely wrong here as your not storing supertyes of `Content` but subtypes. Extends on the other hand wouldn't add any additional value).

`List<Content>` should work with the latest snapshots for `MongoTemplate` as we fixed quite some bugs since the last milestone release. If you're using our repository abstraction make sure `Content` is an abstract class containing the id property. There is an open [issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATADOC-131) you might wanna watch for us to support interfaces as repository managed types as well.

Comment: Hi Oliver. Thank you. You were rigth. With 1.0.0.M3 everithig works just as I expected, i see additional '_class' property. But now i have this property for all my classes. I need this property only for objects stored in this collection. Can you help me with this? Is it possible to have this property in certain classes?

Comment: Any idea if this change with M4?  It does not seem to work as described here any more.

Comment: does the collection needs any annotation over it?

Answer (score 5):

Just as an FYI (since we hunted for this for a good morning after trying to figure out why we were getting our objects returned as `LinkedHashMaps` of the members), this issue also occurs (in 1.0.2.RELEASE), when you try to store a `Collection<Content>` in the form:

```
@Document(collection = "items")
public class Item{
@Id
private ObjectId id;   
private Collection<Content> content;
...
}
```

The solution, as above, is to switch it to a `List<Content>`.

Answer (score 0):

Code `List<? super Content> content;` creates list with elements, with type, which **extends** class Content. As I see, Content - is an interface, so you cannot specify generic binding for it.

I'd suggest you to create abstract class Content and extend this class by your classes **YoutubeVideo** and **Image**. After that, code `List<? super Content> content;` will work fine.

Sergey.

Comment: Hi, Sergei. No you wrong. JSON after save is the same. Issue is not in java class, it is in serializer/deserializer. Saved JSON without any real class id, and that's why not possible to deserialize JSON.